# How many number of lines can chrome print at once

Tags: google-chrome

When I try to print a content of an array which consists huge amount of data, results in blank page. But when I print few index of the same array it's shown on the page. May I know is there is any limit for data presentation in google chrome.
OR It's my illusion.

Comment: Define "huge amount" and define "blank page". Is it still loading, or has it finished loading but appears blank?

Comment: @DrZoo hi, thanks for your response, here huge amount is array size is arr [1333][889][48] and output of array i.e single value is consuming single line. And blank page: after loading is finish it still show blank page.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely the page is still being rendered while it is loading the data. You must wait for the DOM to load, which you can tell if the icon in the tab is a spinner.

As for any "limit," that would be the remaining memory on your computer until either the OS decides to kill Chrome or the computer crashes.

Comment: thanks for response, I to have the same answer in my mind but i'am expecting for the different answer if there is any. Thanks :)